# Generating hi-resolution image from transformed UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, cgcontext, cgaffinetransform

I have been getting a trouble to generate hi-resolution image from transformed UIImageViews.
I have a canvas view that contains several views transformed by user fingers.
So I try to render the image of those views based on transforms of them.
Here is code snap what I use for a view.

```
CGSize canvasSize = CGSizeMake(HIRES_WIDTH, HIRES_WIDTH);
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(HIRES_WIDTH / canvasView.frame.size.width, HIRES_WIDTH / canvasView.frame.size.width);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvasSize);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGPoint center = imageView.center;
CGSize size = imageView.bounds.size;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(center.x - size.width, center.y - size.height, size.width, size.height);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, photoImageView.transform);
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, scaleTransform);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

[photoImageView.image drawInRect:frame];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But I'm getting offset difference at final image.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: HIRES_WIDTH? HIRES_WIDTH?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(center.x - size.width, center.y - size.height, size.width, size.height);
```

To this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(center.x - size.width / 2, center.y - size.height / 2, size.width, size.height);
```

Comment: It didn't help me. Offset difference is according to scale factor of transform of UIImageView.